# Data is not displayed in the grid using kendo grid UI that has child array for Angular 4

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

Error: Getting "Cannot read property 'stats' of undefined

JSON:

this.obj1: Array(5)
    [0]: data1
        id: 1,
        name: AAA,
        stats: Array(4)
            [0] : data 2
                shortname: '1',
                value: 23,
                address: '123 wilson dr',
                subHeader: true,
                subHeaders: [{.... }]

Kendo UI:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="obj1" [scrollable]="'scrollable'" [style.height.px]="400">
  <ng-template kendoGridNoRecordsTemplate>
    <b>No statistics found!</b>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="column.stats" let-column>
    <kendo-grid-column title="{{column.shortname}}" [width]="90" *ngIf="!column.subHeader; else elseBlock">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate>
        {{column.value}}
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <kendo-grid-column-group title="{{column.shortname}}" [locked]="false" [width]="120">
        <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="column.subHeaders" let-dataItem let-column>
          <kendo-grid-column title="{{column.subHeaderLbl}}" [width]="90">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
              {{column.statValue}}
            </ng-template>
          </kendo-grid-column>
        </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-column-group>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="column.stats" let-column>
```

to

```
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="column?.stats" let-column>
```

You are trying to show the data before its available, you can use **safe operator** `?` for this.

Comment: Thank you Vivek, able to view the data in the grid but showing "[object, object]" instead of showing acutal data for those child arrays

Comment: Thats because you are not pointing exact data, data you are trying to show is still json , that should be string , 

and yes ,Will you please upvote and accept the answer ?